# Plot companies on a custom interactive map

Tags: jquery, flash, google-maps, dictionary

I've been tasked with creating an interactive sector map that has over 200 companies plotted on it. The map would be of the UK with the location of each company plotted as a dot. On hover there will be a popup box that shows all the info for each company.

What would be the best to build this? Is there any kind of pre-built Jquery or css maps out there that I could adjust to my needs?

As a side note, I'd need to hook this up to Wordpress.

Comment: I feel like you could accomplish this with minimal effort using the Google-Maps API, and some javascript.

Comment: I've proposed Google Maps, is there an option for more custom graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"best" is always tricky. Yes, google maps can be embedded but you have to watch the terms and conditions. For a really free solution use openlayers with openstreetmap background data.

Answer (score 0):

[MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) has a [MapBuilder plugin for WordPress](http://tools.mapquest.com/map-builder-for-wordpress/). I've never used it, but I thought of it when I read your question and noticed that you want to use this with WordPress.  I'm not sure how well it would perform with over 200 companies plotted on it, but it might be worth a look, and might be easier than a full-fledged custom solution.

If the MapBuilder plugin isn't customizable enough, MapQuest also offers JavaScript and Flash APIs that could accomplish what you need to do.  They offer both "[licensed](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products)" (proprietary data) and "[open](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open)" (openstreetmap) versions of their APIs, which you can read about on their [Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com/) website.  I personally like the way the MapQuest APIs handle decluttering, so if you have a few company locations that are in the same general area, the points will be separated (visually) on the map enough so that they stand out.  Here's an [example](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/poi#declutter).